# Share something in Facebook ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

My idea is simple I want that people who sees new news or event in my page could share that in facebook. I want to do this through a .aspx page. 
Is this possible? If so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are for all the major social sites, just add links on your master page, and populate them in its code behind:

```
    gplus.HRef = "https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?title=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Page.Title) + "&amp;url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    facebook.HRef = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?t=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Page.Title) + "&amp;u=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    linkedin.HRef = "http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;title=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Page.Title) + "&amp;url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    myspace.HRef = "http://www.myspace.com/Modules/PostTo/Pages/?t=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Page.Title) + "&amp;u=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    twitter.HRef = "http://twitter.com/share?text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Page.Title) + "&amp;url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

google plus is for g+1 (plus one) as well...

Comment: this only share the page! not the posts!

Comment: @Diogo: you haven't specified that, but I hope you were not intending to spam with the whole text - Facebook will create a summary description from the first text that appears in the body of your page. A list of thumbnails will all be selected from available images on your page. To control the exact preview content have a look at Sharing Rich Media section on this link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/